# jquery .submit(handler) doesn't appear to be detecting form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

so I'm trying to intercept a javascript form submission using jquery, and having some issues. I put Spring in the tags because I wonder if the issue could be that I'm using a spring form:form tag, rather than just a straight html form. Basically, the handler seems to be totally ignored, with the submission going on regardless.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
function submitForm(functionName){
    var form = document.getElementById("evalAdminForm");
    //does some stuff
    form.submit();
}

$('form').submit(function(){
    alert("SUBMITDETECTED");
});

<form:form commandName="evaluation" id="evalAdminForm" name="evalAdminForm" method="post">
    //the form is in here
</form:form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Submit events fire when forms are submitted manually, not in response to JavaScript calling the submit method.

If you are going to trigger form submission using JS (and there is almost never a time when doing so is better than having a submit button) then you need to manually fire any other functions you want to run at the same time.

Comment: I appreciate the response! I'm just a grunt though, and it's the policy of my project's leader that we use buttons to call javascript routines which execute the submit. I'll bring up your thoughts with him though.

What we're trying to do is set up a way to have a method in one of our base jsp's detect the submit from whatever jsp includes the first one, and then disables the buttons, in an attempt to stop the majority of double submits before the server has to deal with them.

Any suggestions other than use submit buttons and then use jquery to detect the submit?